# How to resolve the badboxes and other warningss

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, miktex

I'm new to LateX and these errors are giving me a tough time to understand what they are and not sure of fixing them. Please help me resolve below errors.

bibdata.bib file compiled with no errors.

However thesis.tex file gives me bad boxes errors and other warnings as shown below. Please help me resolving them.Please let me know ,incase, if you need any other information in resolving this problem.

### Here are the errors:

```
thesis.tex
101
LaTeX Warning: Citation `moni13' on page 1 undefined on input line 101.
thesis.tex
116
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:image1' on page 3 undefined on input line 116.
thesis.tex
125

thesis.tex
66
Overfull \hbox (21.68121pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 66--66
[] []
thesis.tex
80
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 80--80
thesis.tex
84
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--85
```

### This is the console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))))
No file thesis.aux.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"))))
[0{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \hbox (21.68121pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 66--66
[] [] 
[1] [3]
No file thesis.toc.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 80--80

[4]
No file thesis.lot.
[5]
No file thesis.lof.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--85

[6]
CHAPTER 1.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `moni13' on page 1 undefined on input line 101.

[1] [2]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:image1' on page 3 undefined on input line 116.

<image1.png, id=31, 289.08pt x 192.72pt> <use image1.png>



[7] [8]
No file thesis.bbl.
(thesis.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiK
TeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 
2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9
/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on thesis.pdf (14 pages, 126299 bytes).
SyncTeX written on thesis.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on thesis.log.
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
The style file: acm.bst
Database file #1: bibdata.bib
Warning--entry type for "Djebber11" isn't style-file defined
--line 45 of file bibdata.bib
Warning--entry type for "Pooyan07" isn't style-file defined
--line 106 of file bibdata.bib
Warning--entry type for "Nutzinger11" isn't style-file defined
--line 115 of file bibdata.bib
Warning--entry type for "Asad11" isn't style-file defined
--line 124 of file bibdata.bib
Too many commas in name 1 of "Ankit Chadha, Neha Satam, Rakshak Sood, Dattatray Bade" for entry Chadha13
while executing---line 1086 of file acm.bst
Too many commas in name 1 of "Ankit Chadha, Neha Satam, Rakshak Sood, Dattatray Bade" for entry Chadha13
while executing---line 1127 of file acm.bst
Warning--empty publisher in asur13
(There were 2 error messages)

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:


You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE! Most of these are warnings and no error messages, especially the overfull boxes and the missing bibliography references. The real error message is here: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe did not succeed`. Does it generate a valid pdf file? Could you provide us some code - [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a line `Output written on thesis.pdf (14 pages, 126299 bytes).`
about 25 lines from the end that reports the successful completion of the
latex process.

the failure here is in the attempt to process the bibliography with bibtex.
this failure has short-circuited the "extended" compile procedure defined
by miktex.  (this contradicts your statement that
"bibdata.bib file compiled with no errors.")

fix the `.bib` file first, according to the errors reported in lines 1006 and 1127
of the `acm.bst` file by the bibtex report.  (for details, see the `.blg` file.)

then remove the `.aux` files and compile again.